# Django: query set, multiple filters. Can i set the order in which the WHERE clause is formed so that it will help me in indexing

Tags: mysql, django

I have the following query in django:

```
            end_date = timezone.now()
            start_date = end_date + timedelta(-5*365)
            queryset = (
                            DailyPriceHistory
                            .objects
                            .filter(symbol=symbol,datetime_utc__range=(start_date, end_date))
                            .order_by('datetime')
                            .order_by('creation_time')
                            .values_list('high','low','open','datetime','close','creation_time')
                        )
```

the Sql it generates is

```
SELECT `daily_price_history`.`high`,
       `daily_price_history`.`low`,
       `daily_price_history`.`open`,
       `daily_price_history`.`datetime`,
       `daily_price_history`.`close`,
       `daily_price_history`.`creation_time`
FROM `daily_price_history`
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`datetime_utc`
        BETWEEN '2015-12-04 18:43:28.710229'
            AND '2020-12-02 18:43:28.710229'
        AND `daily_price_history`.`symbol` = 'A')
ORDER BY `daily_price_history`.`creation_time` ASC
```

Currently i have `symbol` and `datatime` as seperately indexed columns

I found why the filter sequence is not followed. i.e `.filter(symbol=symbol,datetime_utc__range=(start_date, end_date))`

I wanted

```
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`symbol` = 'A'
   AND `daily_price_history`.`datetime_utc`
      BETWEEN '2015-12-04 18:43:28.710229'
          AND '2020-12-02 18:43:28.710229')
```

but it uses

```
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`datetime_utc`
           BETWEEN '2015-12-04 18:43:28.710229'
               AND '2020-12-02 18:43:28.710229'
           AND `daily_price_history`.`symbol` = 'A')
```

Also i dont see `order_by('datetime')` in the sql, is this because `datetime` is indexed

Comment: Your question is not focused as you have multiple questions in it. To sum it up:
Why do you think order of statement matter, also what do you think using two times order_by should produce https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE (foo) AND (bar)
```

optimizes the same as

```
WHERE (bar) AND (foo)
```

However, these are useful in *different* situations:

```
INDEX(a,b)
INDEX(b,a)
```

You need

```
INDEX(symbol, datetime)
```

regardless of the order in the `WHERE`.

But this is efficient because

```
WHERE symbol = '...'        -- Equality test (put first in index)
  AND datetime BETWEEN ...  -- range test (put last in index)
```

This may not be performed efficiently, regardless of the index:

```
WHERE symbol IN (...)       -- IN() is harder than = to optimize
  AND datatime BETWEEN ...
```

Comment: can you also see a similar question i have asked, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150483/mysql-how-to-speed-up-an-sql-query-for-getting-data`. Here i am using where with `IN` and `greater than`. SO in this case also will index does not have any efficiency

Comment: OK, this Q&A talks about `=`, that one talks about `IN`.  Notice how there can be big differences in the Answer for seemingly small differences in the `WHERE`.  Seems like I answered the `WHERE id > ...` in yet another Q&A.  The answer involving `PARTITION` may be the best for all of them.