# MYSQL: how to speed up an sql Query for getting data

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause, sql-in

I am using Mysql database.

I have a table `daily_price_history` of stock values stored with the following fields. It has `11 million+` rows

```
id
symbolName
symbolId
volume
high
low
open
datetime
close
```

So for each stock `SymbolName` there are various daily stock values. And the data is now more than 11 million rows,

The following sql try to get the last 100 days of daily data for a set of 1500 symbols

```
SELECT `daily_price_history`.`id`,
       `daily_price_history`.`symbolId_id`,
       `daily_price_history`.`volume`,
       `daily_price_history`.`close`
FROM `daily_price_history`
WHERE (`daily_price_history`.`id` IN
         (SELECT U0.`id`
          FROM `daily_price_history` U0
          WHERE (U0.`symbolName` = `daily_price_history`.`symbolName`
                 AND U0.`datetime` >= 1598471533546))
       AND `daily_price_history`.`symbolName` IN (A,AA, ...... 1500 symbols Names)
```

I have the table indexed on `symbolName` and also `datetime`

For getting 130K (i.e 1500 x 100 ~ 150000) rows of data it takes 20 secs.

Also i have `weekly_price_history` and `monthly_price_history` tables, and I try to run the similar sql,  they take less time for the same number (130K) of rows, because they have less data in the table than daily.

`weekly_price_history` getting `150K` rows takes `3s`. The total number of rows in it are `2.5million`

`monthly_price_history` getting `150K` rows takes `1s`. The total number of rows in it are `800K`

So how to speed up the thing when the size of table is large.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter: I don't see the point for the subquery at all. Presumably, your query could filter directly in the `where` clause:

```
select id, symbolid_id, volume, close
from daily_price_history
where datetime >= 1598471533546 and symbolname in ('A', 'AA', ...)
```

Then, you want an index on `(datetime, symbolname)`:

```
create index idx_daily_price_history 
    on daily_price_history(datetime, symbolname)
;
```

The first column of the index matches on the predicate on `datetime`. It is not very likley, however, that the database will be able to use the index to filter `symbolname` against a large list of values.

An alternative would be to put the list of values in a table, say `symbolnames`.

```
create table symbolnames (
    symbolname varchar(50) primary key
);
insert into symbolnames values ('A'), ('AA'), ...;
```

Then you can do:

```
select p.id, p.symbolid_id, p.volume, p.close
from daily_price_history p
inner join symbolnames s on s.symbolname = p.symbolname
where s.datetime >= 1598471533546
```

That should allow the database to use the above index. We can take one step forward and try and add the 4 columns of the `select` clause to the index:

```
create index idx_daily_price_history_2 
    on daily_price_history(datetime, symbolname, id, symbolid_id, volume, close)
;
```

Comment: So you mean `daily_price_history(datetime, symbolname)` will be faster inspite of having single index for `datetime` and `symbolname`

Comment: I tried to index both the columns, still it takes 16s. Can this be done in 5sec

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: did you use the new version of the query, that I suggested at the beginning of the answer?

Comment: you mean without subquery. NO. Because this query is generated by Django's prefetch_realted and subquery thing. BUt i will try without that

Answer (score 0):

When you add `INDEX(a,b)`, remove `INDEX(a)` as being no longer necessary.

Your dataset and query may be a case for using `PARTITIONing`.

```
PRIMARY KEY(symbolname, datetime)

PARTITION BY RANGE(datetime) ...
```

This will do "partition pruning":  `datetime >= 1598471533546`.  Then the `PRIMARY KEY` will do most of the rest of the work for `symbolname in ('A', 'AA', ...)`.

Aim for about 50 partitions; the exact number does not matter.  Too many partitions may hurt performance; too few won't provide effective pruning.

Yes, get rid of the subquery as GMB suggests.

Meanwhile, it sounds like Django is getting in the way.

Some discussion of partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint